# Query and Update

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to query a database records and update at the same time.
the field `UserSerial` in database needs to be increased by 1 to create a kind of internal serial number, I am using a variable name `counter` to do that.

When I run the code, I see that the highest counted number (number of records in database) is stored in the `UserSerial`.

Can someone have a look at my code and tell me what my mistake is?

```
public class UsersMenu_Fill_usersSerialNumber {
PreparedStatement statement;
PreparedStatement statementUPD;
private Connection con = null;
private Connection conUPD = null;
private String sql_qry;
private String sql_upd;
int counter = 0;

public void UsersMenu_Fill_usersSerialNumber(){

     DBModule.ConnectDataBase.ConnectDataBase_Method();

     con = DBModule.ConnectDataBase.ConnectDataBase_Method();  
     conUPD = DBModule.ConnectDataBase.ConnectDataBase_Method(); 

    sql_qry = "select UserSerial from users";
    sql_upd = "update users set UserSerial = ?";
    try {
        statement = con.prepareStatement(sql_qry);
        statementUPD = conUPD.prepareStatement(sql_upd);

        ResultSet rslt = statement.executeQuery();

        while (rslt.next()){

            String FieldToChange = rslt.getString("UserSerial");
            int FieldToChange_int = Integer.parseInt(FieldToChange);
            counter++;
            FieldToChange_int = counter;
            statementUPD.setString(1, String.valueOf(FieldToChange_int));
            statementUPD.executeUpdate();

          }
        statement.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UsersMenu_Fill_usersSerialNumber.class.getName        ()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }     
   }
}
```

Comment: Take care of Java naming conventions. Variable names should start with lower case character

Comment: You miss the `WHERE` clause in your update Statement. That's why alway every record is updated

Comment: Also why you set `int FieldToChange_int = Integer.parseInt(FieldToChange);` and override it two lines later? I think `FieldToChange_int = counter;` should be `FieldToChange_int += counter;` or somethink like that

Comment: BTW: to get unique numbers you can use a sequence http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sequence/

Answer (score 0):

So, there's a couple of things you need to know/do.  Firstly, you need to pull back a unique identifier for your row, and use that identifier in your update sql to indicate which row should be updated.  I'm going to assume that you've got an ID column on your users table, and use that.

Secondly, you need to retrieve that ID in your select statement, rather then the userSerial which you don't actually need to retrieve.

Then as you loop through, you need to uniquely update the value based on a where clause in the update statement that you specify with your unique id, ID.

I updated your function only to make demonstrate.  I did not test this at all, it's just a guide to get you moving.

```
public void UsersMenu_Fill_usersSerialNumber(){

    DBModule.ConnectDataBase.ConnectDataBase_Method();

    con = DBModule.ConnectDataBase.ConnectDataBase_Method();
    conUPD = DBModule.ConnectDataBase.ConnectDataBase_Method();

    sql_qry = "select ID from users";
    sql_upd = "update users set UserSerial = ? where ID = ?";
    try {
        statement = con.prepareStatement(sql_qry);
        statementUPD = conUPD.prepareStatement(sql_upd);

        ResultSet rslt = statement.executeQuery();

        while (rslt.next()){
            Long id = statement.getLong("ID");
            counter++;
            statementUPD.setString(1, String.valueOf(counter));
            statementUPD.setLong(2, String.valueOf(id));
            statementUPD.executeUpdate();

        }
        statement.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UsersMenu_Fill_usersSerialNumber.class.getName        ()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```